# How can I launch multiple instances of a job concurrently (Quartz schedulers)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, jobs

I have a scheduler that calls a service that process different entities taking as an argument the ids from the database.

This scheduler launches a job when the user presses a button in the front, this sends a list of ids to the scheduler (the list that is being used to ).

My problem is that when I try to launch more than one job at the same time (ex. two users press the button at the same time) using the scheduleASAP function, the jobs start working but apparently they start using the same piece of code, so they start taking the entities which were supposed to be processed only by one of the jobs and in the end, several entities end up being wrong or not being processed correctly.

Why could this be happening?